# Compiling MXML files into multiple SWF files using mxmlc compiler

Tags: apache-flex, flash, msbuild, mxml, mxmlc

I have a few mxml files that I want compiled into their respective SWF files using a configuration file. At the moment I can get 1 mxml file compiled into it's respective SWF file by using the file-spec attribute in the configuration file but how would I go about compiling multiple mxml files at once? Do I have a separate configuration file for each? I'm using MSBUILD and the mxmlc compiler.

This is how I specified the mxml file to be compiled:

```
<file-specs>
    <path-element>..\somePath\myFile.mxml</path-element>
</file-specs>
```